subprocess.Popen fails to set the name of executable
According to the documentation of Popen, it seems possible, in POSIX systems, to set the name of the process as it is returned by ps:

The executable argument specifies a replacement program to execute. It is very seldom needed. When  shell=False , executable replaces the program to execute specified by args. However, the original args is still passed to the program. Most programs treat the program specified by args as the command name, which can then be different from the program actually executed. On POSIX, the args name becomes the display name for the executable in utilities such as ps.

On my Ubuntu 22.04 machine, if I run the following python script:
import subprocess

with subprocess.Popen(["foo", "10"], executable="sleep", shell=False) as process:
    pass

and then run ps -ae in another terminal, the last lines of output are
  22854 ?        00:00:00 python3.10
  22857 ?        00:00:00 sleep
  22860 pts/0    00:00:00 ps


I would expect to see foo instead of sleep. Could you please explain me what I am getting wrong?

On Linux it depends on the ps options. ps w shows foo 10

So this question is about ps, not Python.

The question is about an example suggested in the official docs that I cannot reproduce.

You should be able to reproduce it as I did, by using the appropriate ps option.

"the args name becomes the display name for the executable in utilities such as ps". Would "one of the possible" be more correct?

What you're not understanding is that ps can also display the actual executable name, not just the display name.

"display name" doesn't mean "name that is displayed".

@Barmar So this is the correct answer to my question ("what I am getting wrong?"). Please post it as an answer.

As I said earlier, that's off-topic for SO. Ask about ps options in [unix.se].

It doesn't change the program name in ps; when it works it changes the program name in ps -f.
Note that this also can't be set arbitarily; some progams are unhappy with garbage in argv[0] (which is how this works).
[Others are talking about default ps options; but question has an OS tag; this doesn't completely close default options but I would at this point suggest my answer is likely accurate with shipped defaults.]

So the documentation is partially inexact. By the way, what is the rationale of "-f" to trigger a different name?

@JtTest The OS stores both the display name and executable name. Different ps options show one or the other.

And different versions of ps have different default options. The example works as expected on MacOS without any options.

@Barmar: Oh fun.

ps w also works to show the display name.
